# Magento getData() vs getFieldName() in model

Tags: magento2, model, resource-model

After `load('id')` function in model, we can get data by either `model->getData('field_name')` or `model->getFieldName()`.

I know that both functions are provided by `DataObject` class but what I want to know is

1. Is there any different between them ?
2. What should I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a bit of different, model->getFieldName() is a magic method so this will be public and in Magento 2 we can create plugins to manipulate output of public methods

(i.e)
Lets assume

- value of field_name is **foo**
- there is plugin(https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) created which changes the value to **bar**
- model->getData('field_name') will return **foo**
- model->getFieldName() will return **bar**

It is always advisable to use model->getFieldName() so can take advantage of plugins in Magento 2.

I Hope this explanation helps.